# Create new QuarterEnd column in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

I'm trying to create a new column with the calendar year's quarter end date (e.g. if today is 4 August, this quarter's end date would be 30 September).

My DataFrame has a set of dates in a column called `df['dates']`. Sample below:

```
03/08/2017
26/02/2015
31/12/2012
16/04/2014
13/04/2016
```

This is the code I am using, which is not working:

```
df['q_date'] = pd.datetime(pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd(startingMonth=(pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.month)))
```

I have also tried looping through but have been unsuccessful.

Any ideas are most appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert each date to period objects, and then take their end times (which are timestamps).

```
df = df.assign(q_date=[pd.Period(d, freq='Q').end_time for d in df['dates']])
>>> df
        dates     q_date
0  03/08/2017 2017-03-31
1  26/02/2015 2015-03-31
2  31/12/2012 2012-12-31
3  16/04/2014 2014-06-30
4  13/04/2016 2016-06-30
```

Comment: do you have any thoughts on how to do this for the last date of the previous quarter?

Comment: Subtract one from the period: `df.assign(q_date=[(pd.Period(d, freq='Q') - 1).end_time for d in df['dates']])`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks mate.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply add `pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd(0)`:

```
df['qdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) + pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd(0)
print (df)
         date      qdate
0  03/08/2017 2017-03-31
1  26/02/2015 2015-03-31
2  31/12/2012 2012-12-31
3  16/04/2014 2014-06-30
4  13/04/2016 2016-06-30
```

**Timeings**:

```
#5000 rows
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [19]: %timeit df.assign(q_date=[pd.Period(d, freq='Q').end_time for d in df['date']])
1 loop, best of 3: 1.84 s per loop

In [20]: %timeit pd.to_datetime(df['date']) + pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd(0)
1 loop, best of 3: 913 ms per loop
```

---

```
#50000 rows
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [23]: %timeit df.assign(q_date=[pd.Period(d, freq='Q').end_time for d in df['date']])
1 loop, best of 3: 18.5 s per loop

In [24]: %timeit pd.to_datetime(df['date']) + pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd(0)
1 loop, best of 3: 9.13 s per loop
```

Comment: Have you run any timings between the two methods?  Period objects are generally slow and I was curious if this method was faster.